# HTML5 Search Field Icon Press Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html5 search field `<input type='search'>` and I have a jquery on key up event that monitors it and sorts. But if I press the little search icon x that appears on the right it doesn't trigger the jquery keyup, but pressing the delete key or backspace does.

How can I monitor the little exit and if it's pressed "unsort"?

Comment: try use 'change' event, that should be added to this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use onsearch event

```
<input type=search onsearch="javascript:alert('SEARCH: ' + this.value);" />
```